# JPA Query annotation over ManyToMany relationship works not properly

Tags: java, jquery, sql, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to implement an example like this: A Person class has a list of places that it likes. But when I want to query it, I want result as each person with only the most favorite place(just the first one not all of them). So I have done this:

```
@Entity
class Person{

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_favorite_place",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @OrderColumn(name="favorite_place_order")
    List<Place> favoritePlaces;
}
```

And in repository, I did:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select person0_.id as id1_0_0_, person0_.age as age2_0_0_, person0_.name as name3_0_0_, favoriteme1_.person_id as person_id1_1_1_, place2_.id as place_id2_1_1_, favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order as favorite3_1_, place2_.id as id1_3_2_, place2_.invented as invented2_3_2_, place2_.name as name3_3_2_ from person person0_ left outer join person_favorite_place favoriteme1_ on person0_.id=favoriteme1_.person_id left outer join place place2_ on favoriteme1_.place_id=place2_.id where person0_.id=:personId  and favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order = 0", nativeQuery = true)
    Person getPersonWithFavoritePlace(@Param("personId") Long personId);

}
```

As expected, the query needs to return 1 Place for each Person but it always returns all the places that Person likes. What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Do you have to use native query?

Comment: @pirho no actually. I just want to find a way to solve my problem. But this is the only way that I have found up to now

Comment: When a `Person` object is returned whether by query or by `find` it will never load just one `Place` ... because that `Person` has all of those favourite places. Just use JPQL projection and return a Person object and a Place object. Ample docs on the internet to do that

Comment: I can do that @DN1 but it is a problem of performance. 2 different sql queries make extra load on db. So I have to do it on one round. I am still looking for if there is a way to make it happen like that without writing code but JPA

Comment: There is not necessarily two queries on projection usually it is just one. Also the performance might not be so straightforwardly determined. One bad query can be worse that two not so bad queries. And projection is better way to do it than return a "List" with just one item

Comment: Nobody told you to do 2 queries! I said use JPQL projection = 1 query returning a Person and a Place

Comment: @DN1 I do not understand. Is my native sql wrong? if it is not how does that return something different from what I am looking for? The native sql has been built just exacly on "findOne" basic repo method's query. I have just added   "and favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order = 0" part. I have enabled show-sql property so I got it